# WSO2 Identity Server Authentication

Tags: server, wso2, identity

I have a requirement that, I need to authenticate the User Credentials via WSO2 Identity Server. The user credentials are stored in the separate Database. Can anyone explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

All of the WSO2 products are based on [WSO2 Carbon framework](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/) *(an award-winning, light-weight, service-oriented platform for all WSO2 products)*, and can be configured to use a existing centralized user management systems as the user store.

In WSO2 Carbon-based products, there are four user store manager classes that implement the `AbstractUserStoreManager` class. You can select one of those classes according to the user store that you have in your environment.

1. org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager
2. org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager
3. org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager
4. org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryLDAPUserStoreManager

You can write a custom JDBC user store manager, if your data in RDBM system. Have a look on [Writing a Custom User Store Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager), specially check on [Implementing a custom JDBC user store manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager#WritingaCustomUserStoreManager-ImplementingacustomJDBCuserstoremanager)

Answer (score 0):

When a JDBC user store is used as a primary or secondary user store, the user details will be stored in “UM_USER” table upon user creation. Following are the columns of the table.
UM_ID
UM_USER_NAME
UM_USER_PASSWORD
UM_SALT_VALUE
UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE
UM_CHANGED_TIME
UM_TENANT_ID

All WSO2 products are defult shipped with H2 database internally. H2 database stores registry and user management data.
This H2 data can easily achived by enabling the H2DatabaseConfiguration in carbon.xml that located /repository/conf.
Follow the following configuration steps to achive H2 database in browser.

1. Open the carbon.xml file and paste the H2DatabaseConfiguration as follows.
   Note: Don't uncomment the H2DatabaseConfiguration which already there.

`<H2DatabaseConfiguration>
        <property name="web"/>
        <property name="webPort">8082</property>
        <property name="webAllowOthers"/>

</H2DatabaseConfiguration>`

2. Start the server.
3. Direct your browser to http://localhost:8082
4. Fill the JDBC url, username and password as follows.
   JDBC url: jdbc:h2:/repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB
   username: wso2carbon
   password: wso2carbon

If anyone want replace H2 database with different kind of databases like MySQL you can do it as follows. Refer[1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+MySQL